# Is Memory leaked by a kernel module is returned to system when we remove that module?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Suppose I have a kernel module which is loaded in to kernel dynamically. This kernel module is having some memory leak. If i remove that module the leaked memory by the module is returned to the system ?  or still the memory is unavailable for usage?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no automatic memory collection in the kernel. If you allocate it, you're responsible for keeping track of it and releasing it before your module is unloaded.

Comment: The kernel does however offer the devres API - [device managed resources](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/devres.txt) which has calls like `devm_kmalloc()`. When the associated device is removed (because the module is unloaded, for instance), the device-managed resource is freed automatically.